# visible indication that a cell is not evaluatable

Tags: front-end

Occasionally I make cells not evaluatable.  Is there any way to have some sort of visible indication (automatic) that reminds me if a cell is not evaluatable.

One example of why I do this is that we have multiple environments: Production, UAT, and Development.  I use different cells for each one, and only set the one I need to be evaluatable.  Another example would be having test data that I need, for some of the time, but not for other times.  I have, on occasion, run something with the wrong cell set up as evaluatable. I thought it might be helpful if there was a visual indicator, without having to lookup the cell properties, to remind me which cell is evaluatable.

Comment: I suppose you mean some visible indication more obvious than the little horizontal bar added to the cell bracket (just below the top triangle) when you remove the `Editable` property ?

Answer (score 5):

Here's another stylesheet way:

```
Cell[
 StyleData["Input"],
 CellBracketOptions ->
  {
   "Color" ->
    FEPrivate`If[
     FEPrivate`SameQ[
      FrontEnd`CurrentValue[FrontEnd`EvaluationCell[], Evaluatable],
      True
      ],
     GrayLevel[.7],
     GrayLevel[.9]
     ]
   }
 ]
```

This makes the cell bracket very light if it can't be evaluated:

[image]

You could also make it darker or thicker or whatever you want. Check

```
Options[EvaluationCell[], CellBracketOptions]
```

to see what you can play with

Answer (score 4):

You can make the cell appearance depend dynamically on it option values.  For example, edit the stylesheet and add the options to the `"Input"` style:

```
Cell[StyleData["Input"], 
 CellDingbat -> 
  Dynamic[If[CurrentValue[EvaluationCell[], Evaluatable], None, 
    StyleBox["Ø", FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.7]]]]]
```

[image]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[You can see a little horizontal tick on the non-executable cell bracket, but I can't usually see those things anymore in the notebook, at least not reliably. Thanks @ HighPerformanceMark.]

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work.  First, the only way I know how to edit a style sheet, using the menu, I change options in the options inspector.  So, I entered your code into a cell and executed it.  Then when making a cell not evaluatable I did get that little line in the bracket.  But changing the GrayLevel didn't make a difference.  I also did not see the "Ø".  I'm probably not applying your advice properly.

Comment: @MitchellKaplan You can do it with the OptionInspector. It should look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISG10.png -- Or you can select the "Input" style in the stylesheet, execute the menu command Cell > Show Expression, and edit the text so that it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG4av.png

Comment: You can also go to `Edit Stylesheet` in the `Format` menu and copy that `Cell` expression in.